# Java: How to handle multiple threads reporting on the same search space?

Tags: java, multithreading

Lets say I am using `ExecutorService` to spawn threads that perform millions of actions, like updating an individual thread specific counter (no race conditions).  I want to print to the console the current action rate from all the combined threads, once per second.  How can I do this? My main problem is that I dont know gather each threads statistics once per second in a reliable way.

If it helps, the actual application is blockchain hashing, and I want to print the combined hashrate, between all the threads.

So for example (psuedo-code):

```
Runnable hash = () -> {
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            hashStuff();
            reportHashRateInfo(i, otherStuff); // How do I do this?
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
};

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
executor.submit(hash);

printCombinedHashRateInfo(); // and this
```

Comment: One way to solve this would be to have `reportHashRateInfo(i, otherStuff);` collect the intermediate statistics into a shared `Collection`. On the other side of the equation, have a thread that wakes up every second and aggregates the data present in the shared collection and prints it out to the console. This thread is a listener that you can start before launching any of the hashing threads.

Comment: You mean something like `StatisticsAggregator.submitStats(i, otherStuff);` which puts the info into something like a linkedlist?